# Quick Question: using expectation as a scalar

Tags: probability, statistics, monte-carlo

I'd like to ask a question about possible rules of expectation when we can and can't use them "as if" they were scalars.

Given Random Variables: $X_i \underset{iid}{\sim} z$ forming a random sample of z where z is some distribution and two given functions f and g.

lets define $\mathbb{E}_{g}[f(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(X)g(X)~dx$ as the weighted expectation of f wrt to g.

From my understanding this is a number... it has a value and is not a "random variable" (even though i know constants are technically random variables with constant value)...

so if we were to calculate for example:
$$Var[h(X)] = \sum\limits_{1}^{n}Var_{g}[\mathbb{E}_{g}[f(X_i)]w(X_i)]$$
In this instance, would it be correct to consider the expectation as if it's acting as a scalar (since it's value is constant for each defined observation) and so we could rewrite this as
$$\sum\limits_{1}^{n}\mathbb{E}_{g}[f(X_i)]Var_{g}[w(X_i)]$$
where the $Var_g$ is defined analogously to $\mathbb{E}_{g}$

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have written it, the expected value term is a constant; hence,
$$\sum\limits_{1}^{n}Var_{g}[\mathbb{E}_{g}[f(X_i)]
w(X_i)]
=\sum\limits_{1}^{n}
(\mathbb{E}_{g}[f(X_i)])^2
Var_{g}[
w(X_i)].
$$
Note that is different from what you wrote since $\mathsf{Var}(aX)=a^2\mathsf{Var}(X)\neq a\mathsf{Var}(X)$.

Comment: Ah, yes I had forgotten the squared. many thanks. I'll accept this as the answer in about 5 min (when i can). out of curiosity. what would be the limitation on when we can and can't use it as a scalar? if this is significant I can always create a new question

Comment: @John2Dice No problem. For a scalar-valued random variable (i.e. not a random vector) an expected value is always a constant (nonrandom) unless it is a conditional expectation. As such, you can always treat expected values as constants as was done here.

Comment: Interesting. Random vectors and conditional expectations obey alternative rules. Thanks for that. I'll most likely ask that as a follow up question. Have a good day.

Comment: @John2Dice Yes, the expected value of a random vector will be a (nonrandom) vector. Additionally, conditional expectations are generally going to also be random variables and thus cannot be treated as a scalar.